# How to remove old text from JTextArea so that the document size doesn't exceed a threshold? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

So I wish to output the console to a JTextArea which I can do, however I wish for the text area to be treated like the Eclipse console, and remove old lines once the line count has reached a certain threshold. Such that, once the line count (or character count) has reached a threshold of say, 300, every new line added will delete the first line added meaning that the number of lines (or characters) in the JTextArea's document will never exceed that threshold. How might I do this? Cheers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my question is straight forward enough. I have read the Java docs, and it didn't say anything about this.

Comment: @John, `and it didn't say anything about this.` - not directly. You will not always find a method that does all the functionality that you want. But the point is you can put together different methods to implement the functionality that you want. But you first have to understand how a Document works with the text area and then find out what methods of the Document can be used to remove text from the Document.

Comment: the truth is, i probably could do this, but my code would be a bodge job, and would have not been half as efficient as the code in your answer.

Comment: therefore, this post has been a success

Comment: `the truth is, i probably could do this, but my code would be a bodge job,` - yes, well that is how you learn. We are not here to spoon feed you answers. We expect you to make an effort. I will expect an effort next time before I answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and remove old lines once the line count has reached a certain threshold.

You would use a `DocumentListener` for something like this. You will receive an event every time text is added or removed from the Document. You can then implement your logic to control the lines (or total characters).

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentListner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information and basic examples.

You can also check out [Limit Lines in Document](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/limit-lines-in-document/) for an example that shows how you can limit then number of lines using this approach.